# Space at the end of first cout statement shows at the beginning of second cout

Tags: c++

There's some `cout` statement but the space at the end of the first `cout` statement shows up at the beginning of second `cout` statement. Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Enter the starting countdown value: ";
    int limit;
    cin >> limit;
    int i;
    for (int i = limit; i; i--)
    {
        cout << "i = " << i << "\n";
    }
    cout << "Done now that i = " << i << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Comment: Please show the output you get in comparision to the output you want, with a few different inputs.

Comment: By "space at the end of first cout statement" you mean the blank between "value:" and the quote marks?

Comment: Yes, sorry English is not my mother language. There should be a space printed at the end of the first line but it printed at the beginning of the second line after I input a num.

Comment: Did you try the flushing, as proposed in LightnessRacesinOrbits (now deleted) answer? `cout << "Enter the starting countdown value: " << flush;`  Otherwise the answer by gsamaras is very important for clean programming.

Comment: @Yunnosch tbf I deleted it cos it was wrong :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit May I ask how it was wrong? This is not about your mistake, I thought the same and want to learn about mine. The remaining answer nicely explains the weird 16. But I still want to know about the weird "moved" blank. If you help me find the relevant part in the answer it is sufficient.

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't know why you experience the thing you do. Perhaps your build is out of date. I thought flushing was to blame but I forgot that (unless you turn off this feature, which you didn't) `std::cout` and `std::cin` are "tied" which literally means they prevent that problem from happening (your `std::cin` operation will automatically flush `std::cout`)

Comment: I suppose it's possible there's a bug in that mechanism on your toolchain but we don't know what that toolchain is

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think you might be confusing me with the OP, but nevermind. Thanks for the explanation. May I say that I would consider this explanation of what is NOT the cause would be part of the answering process and hence an upvoteable answer?

Comment: @Yunnosch I was, yes, sorry :D And nope explaining what _isn't_ the answer isn't an answer :P

Answer (score 0):

There is no space there, at least one that can be reproduced, as shown in the screenshot. As @LightnessRacesInOrbit commented though: Flushing periods are implementation-dependent so we can expect reproducibility to vary.

---

### The *real problem* of your code:

You have two variables named `i`: one outside, one inside the for loop.

As a result, the for loop uses the `i` declared in it, and behaves as desired.

However, here:

```
cout << "Done now that i = " << i << "\n";
```

you are printing **an uninitialized variable `i`**.

A strong hint for you to have found the problem would be to read the warnings issued by the compiler, as shown below:

[image]

Also notice the garbage value of `i` being printed when you are done, which is the main indication that something is wrong in your code.

An easy fix would be to change this:

```
for (int i = limit; i; i--)
```

to this:

```
for (i = limit; i; i--)
```

and then the last line of your output would be this:

> Done now that i = 0

Comment: The observation about the uninitialised variable is interesting but probably not what is being asked about

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit please read my updated answer, I mean it's not reproducable (but I know see that you say it is).. Hmm.. Well, interesting or not, it's wrong, so I think it would need to be in the spotlight.

Comment: Flushing periods are implementation-dependent so we can expect reproducibility to vary

Comment: That's what I was thinking when I saw your answer, injected it in mine's.

Comment: Oh, then again, cout is tie'd to cin isn't it

Comment: Hmm @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't understand what you mean, could you please be more analytic? :)

Comment: Thanks your remind! Actually I'm a beginner so I'm just typing from my books for exercise.

Comment: @theglance you are welcome! If you find this answer helpful, you can *accept* it, by clicking on the green mark, just left from this answer! :)